# Svelte goto function not routing to existing page

Tags: routes, svelte

Currently working with SvelteKit and have ran into an issue while trying to route to an already existing page. I have created a /login page with some divs and input on it. I am trying to navigate to the login page after a successful signup has gone through, but it seems the goto function doesn't work as I expected it to. I know the page exists because I can manually type the URL and navigate to it, and the goto function is able to bring me to pages that do not already exist. Looking for some guidance here as I am stumped!

Here is my goto function I wrote to be used across the application in the future.

```js
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  import { goto } from "$app/navigation";

  export function routeToPage(route: string, replaceState: boolean) {
    goto(`/${route}`, { replaceState });
  }
</script>
```

Here is my function in the signup page handling the submit button (not posted).

```js
  import { routeToPage } from "$lib/components/goto.svelte";

  let email = "";
  let password = "";
  let confirmPassword = "";
  let registrationSuccessful = false;

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log("Email:", email);
    console.log("Password:", password);
    console.log("Confirm Password:", confirmPassword);
    
    // logic here for signup
    routeToPage("login", true);
  }
</script>
```

No errors show up when trying to route to my login page, the websites URL also does not change. Errors of course pop up when trying to navigate to a random page that does not exist and my URL changes to said random page. Thank you for the help in advance.

Edit: This was the documentation I was referencing - https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation

Comment: Does `goto('/your_route')` alone; without the replace state work?

Comment: it's very hard to answer your question without a Stackblitz your problem might be a million different reasons. 

for example make sure that /login is on the root of the app like localhost:1234/login same 
$app/navigation is not available on ssr make sure you call routeToPage when the page is already in the browser

Comment: The `goto` function didn't seem to function differently with or without the replace state as I was experimenting. @Natumanya Guy

Comment: Based on this information alone, I have no idea why you're getting this behavior, perhaps you could share your project on Stackblitz like @Isaac suggests. A dirty solution would be to create and bind an a tag element using `bind:this` to a variable that you can then call the `.click()` event on. See documentation here - https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-this